# Extended Permissions (Newsfeed) Facebook Graph API App still in development

Tags: facebook-graph-api

On Facebook's [Login Review Page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login) the following is stated:

> Also, if you're the developer of an app and are the only person using
>   it, then your app doesn't need to go through review. Since you're the
>   developer, all app capabilities should be available. You will still
>   need to take your app out of developer mode, but you should be able to
>   do that without going through review.

I'm trying to access the newsfeed of a logged in user of my app through the Graph API. Supposedly this cannot be done without having the read_stream permission, and my console confirms this when I try to log the response of a request to "/me/home". I get the following error:

```
message: "(#200) Requires extended permission: read_stream"
```

However, currently only I, the developer, am using the app. So shouldn't I have access to this capability without going through review? How come I do not? Feel free to ask for specifics.